# How to survive to 6 Reapers rush on Starcraft II Lotv TvT

Tags: starcraft-2

Since LOTV, almost each time I play against Terran (I'm Terran, so TvT), the other guy build 6-8 reapers and go rush before my first Factory unit.

In best cases, I can scout a triple RAX, and in worst cases, when the map is large, I can't scout anything (Terran wall).

I don't like this cheesy opening but I have the feeling the only way to counter this is to do the same build order. Does this mean every Terran should make this opening in TvT matchup?
Or is there other builds that counter, maybe double RAX opening?

Answer (score 2):

This opening is becoming more and more popular these days, but, also, is becoming popular how to handle it.

**First point, SCOUT**

Scout immediately after your first barrack gets finished.

- If you are not able to stick into opponent's base then go and scout for proxies, if you feel like he's cheesing just throw a scan in his main
- If you get into opponent's main and see 2/3 barracks immediately go back and prepare

**Second point, DEFEND**

As soon as you understand what's going on, you need to put on a proper defense.

- Go for a really fast hellions while holding with marines + some scvs (tank) into banshee
- Add 2 more barracks and make also mass reapers
- Reactor first on your barracks (no marines), then adding a factory. You'll get lots of marines + hellions asap

Anyways, you really need to focus with micro and tank with Scvs while waiting for hellions. That's it, I'm sure that if you'll practice a bit with that you'll be able to handle it.

I hope I've been helpful, GL & HF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First point: the problem is Terran usually wall their entrance, preventing any scout. So two methods remains : make 1 reaper or buy a scan. I think making 1 reaper would be a better idea, but this delays the marine production. Thanks anyways, I'll try your defending suggestions next time i'll play.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact build order, but Hellion Reaper/Marine holds fine against 3 Barracks Reaper.

You start with the depot and rax, build 1 reaper to scout, then you start building marines. You build your factory ASAP after the Barracks finished and start to produce Hellions.

Normally, the enemy Terran will attack you with the first reaper and will rally his reinforcements to your base, so you'll head a steady growing army.

You need to be a bit careful with your first 2-3 marines and the first Hellion, but as soon as you get your second Hellion and marines you should be able to overwhelm the reapers.

Still, it's micro intensive, but that's the best counter I've seen by now on the Twitch steams from Polt and Winter.

Answer (score 0):

depot barracks 1 reaper to scout is pretty standard opening. but if you just want to defend you can probably just build reactor and get the marines going. 3 rax 2 reactors and 1 tech lab building marines out of reactors and marauders with good timing on your tech upgrades was decent in hots.